# Missing intitial value for session parameter $AppConnection_SF1 Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: file, parameters, informatica-powercenter

Ok following challenge I am encountering:

I created a parameter file which looks like the following:

$AppConnection_SF1=Salesforce_Produktion

When I run the workflow the session fails with the error message mentioned in my title. But as you can see the parameter session has an intitial value. Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The full parameter file looks like this:

Comment: [GLOBAL]
[ORANGE_REMIGRATION.WF:wf_m_remigration_payments_test.ST:s_m_remigration_payments_test]
[ORANGE_REMIGRATION.WF:wf_m_remigration_payments_test.ST:s_m_tdis_ta_remigration]

$AppConnection_SF1=Salesforce_Produktion
$DBConnection_SOURCE_ORA=ABUEL_TDIS_ROT
$DBConnection_TARGET_ORA=TDISORANGE
$DBConnection_SOURCE_TA=TDISORANGE

Comment: What are the names of your Repository Folder, Workflow and Session where you want to use the parameter? Is it matching the sections named in the parameter file? Can you remove the empty sections?

Comment: Thanks fo your comment, I coul already solve it with the help of Informatica Support. They suggested to list workflow and sessions with the Connections one by one. And I also forgot to save the file as a .prm file.